# Regex deselect anything in the line before match

Tags: regex, power-automate-desktop, deselect

I need to deselect anything in the line before a certain character. My example looks like this.

```
28.01.2023 11:00
GERMANY
OWVA2
07.01.2023 06:00
JAPAN
940-750
Laden
28.01.2023 12:00
FRANCE
ANDY
-
07.01.2023 09:30
NORWAY and SWEDEN
-
07.01.2023 09:30
SPAIN
```

I already have a Regex that selects anything in the line that follows a date (dd.MM.yyyy followed by HH:mm). Now I want to select what follows the date ONLY if the match isn't followed by - or NUMBER-NUMBER in the NEXT line. So basically deselect anything in the line before - or NUMBER-NUMBER. So in this case I want to select Germany, France and Spain. I don't want to select Japan and NORWAY and SWEDEN because they are followed by - or NUMBER-NUMBER.

My regex looks like this:

```
(?<=\d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+[\r\n]+)([ a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßé0-9'-]{3,})+(?![\r\n](\d+)?-(\d+)?)
```

Sorry for this weird example but that is the best I have. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your negative lookahead only prevents matching the last character of the line, because if it's not matched then the match isn't followed by a linefeed and a number dash number anymore.

You can fix that by matching the lookahead before the content you want to capture :

```
(?<=\d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+[\r\n]+)(?!.*[\r\n](\d+)?-(\d+)?)([ a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßé0-9'-]{3,})+
```

You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/CVpxqA/1).